# Upload multiple images from iOS to .net core web api

Tags: ios, swift, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, alamofire

I'm developing an iOS app in Swift which uses .net core 3.0 as backend. I've tried out many suggested answers on how to upload images to .net core backend and succeeded. I've used something like this:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(IFormFileCollection files)
    {
        return await _imageHandler.UploadImage(files);
    }
```

This works perfectly from Postman. I can select multiple images and post them to server.

However, I cannot make it work with Swift. I tried several solutions using **Alamofire** and some other libs but I cannot seem to connect these two parts, **iOS app <=> .net core controller**. The "*files*" property is always null. I read a lot about "*multipart/form-data*" and other content types but I just cannot seem to get it. I know that Alamofire has its own ways of uploading multiple images but all examples I found were with php or node. I would appreciate any example that can show me how to set up these two things. Many thanks!

Comment: It is really easy with CodyFire library

Comment: Where you able to solve this issue?